# HTML positioning: mix % and px with three divs

Tags: html, position, footer

I have a problem with positioning HTML divs:

I want to have a top headline with height 50px and a footer with height 40px.

The whole in-between shall be filled with the div "pad" but it does not fill the whole area.

Dont know where my mistake is.

And..btw..Do i really need jquery for this mickey mouse stuff?

```
</head>
<body>
    <style>

    body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #head{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        border: solid black 1px;

    }
    #pad{
        position: relative;
        border: solid red 1px;
        top: 50px;
        width: 100%;



    }
    #foot{
        position: absolute;
        border: solid green 1px;
        width: 40px;
        bottom: 0px;
    }

    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        var win_h = $(window).height();
        console.log(win_h);
        $('#pad').height(win_h-90);

    </script>

    <div id="head" >HEAD</div>
    <div id="pad">PAD</div>
    <div id="foot">TOOL</div>

</body>
```

Comment: If you need the height to be dynamic, then you will need to do the calculation. If the heights of your head and foot are always the same, you can use absolute positioning to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using absolute positioning and no jquery:
http://jsfiddle.net/adamfullen/6kqT3/

```
body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #head{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        border: solid black 1px;

    }
    #pad{
        position: absolute;
        border: solid red 1px;
        top: 50px;
        bottom: 40PX;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    #foot{
        position: absolute;
        border: solid green 1px;
        width: 40px;        
        height: 40PX;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: Ah thank you. This seems to work!

But one last question about mixing % and px:

If the footer is 10% high and you dont know the px amount. how can you achieve that the PAD-div fills the area up to the footers border?

I tried "margin-bottom: 0px;", but it hadnt any effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Likewise to the example, as long as your footer height is the same as your PAD bottom defitinion, it will work. If you made Foot height: 10%; Your PAD should be bottom:10%; These both are saying 10% of parent element (body), which is same number when applied.

Answer (score 0):

Add 100% height for your body and html. Then using calc expression you can assign the height for the pad division.

```
html,body
{height:100%;}

#head{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid black 1px;

}
#pad{
    position: relative;
    border: solid red 1px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height:calc(100% - 90px);


}
#foot{
    position: absolute;
    border: solid green 1px;
    width: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/N9mLp/1/)